# jQuery - Trouble adding a class to a hyperlink using 'each'

Tags: javascript, jquery, hyperlink, each

I have some Javascript that finds all of the hyperlinks in a page that contain 'google' for example and changes the beginning of the url to another url.

I am trying to add a class to this affected link, however I am getting a lot of 'undefined' errors in the JS console. I have tried alert($(this).innerHTML)) which showed the contents of the hyperlink - clases and whatnot. But for some reason I cannot append a class. I have also tried using this.className += " socks". <del>That also causes an undefined error</del>. I think I am missing something simple!

Also is there a way of using a regex in the search, I am newish to Javascript.

Here is my code:

> ```
> $("a[href*='google']").each(function(){ 
>       this.href = this.href.replace('http://www.google.co.uk','http://www.ask.com');
>       this.href = this.href.replace('http://www.google.com','http://www.ask.com');
>       $(this).addClass("socks");
>   });
> ```

Thanks very much for any help!

Comment: Are you sure that the undefined errors are coming from these lines of code?

Comment: I have looked into this and it turns out that the errors were not caused by this piece of code. Forgot to clean the JS console history.

The code still isn't adding a new class to the hyperlink

Comment: the code you posted should work fine.  I can't see anything wrong with it.  Are you sure there arn't any other errors hiding around?

Comment: Something else must be interfering with the process for some reason. I will get to the bottom of it. Cheers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no error with this code that i can see:

http://jsfiddle.net/p7Sgj/

See this.

Comment: Why would you make it so it looks blank? :P

Comment: lol, well there wasn't anything needed :D it was a rather simple script.

Comment: Actually I was talking about making the links white :P

Comment: arghhhhhhhhhhhh you got me :p

Answer (score 2):

try

```
$("a[href*='google']").each(function(){ 

    var href = $(this).attr('href');
    href.replace('http://www.google.co.uk','http://www.ask.com');
    href.replace('http://www.google.com','http://www.ask.com');
    $(this).attr('href', href);
    $(this).addClass("socks");
});
```

instead of using this.href. I guess your code doesn't reach the addClass part...

Also, use firebug (in case of firefox) or chrome developer tools (in case of chrome) for debugging. You can simply set a breakpoint, add watches, etc...

(In that case, make sure you use a so-called non-minified version of jQuery for easier debugging)

Answer (score 2):

If your HTML code is

```
<a href="http://www.google.co.uk">Hello</a>
<a href="http://www.google.com">World</a>
```

And your CSS is

```
.socks {
    color:#f00;
}
```

Then your code should be working fine.
http://jsfiddle.net/k93TZ/2/
Working here.
It might be your html or css code.